# Angular ng-style on body tag for different page backgrounds?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, ngroute, ng-style

I am new to angular and ngroute and am trying to use ng-style to have a different image background for each page of a website.  Currently it sets the background of all the site's pages, even when I have different controller scope image urls.

My html is like this:

```
<body ng-controller="mainController" ng-style="bodyStyles">
...
   <div id="main">
      <div ng-view></div>
</body>
```

My script:
 var angVenture = angular.module('angVenture', ['ngRoute']);

```
// configure routes
angVenture.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider

        // route for the index page
        .when('/home', {
            templateUrl : 'pages/home.html',
            controller  : 'mainController'
        })

        // route for the about page
        .when('/about', {
            templateUrl : 'pages/about.html',
            controller  : 'aboutController'
        })

 ... more routes.....      

// create the controller
angVenture.controller('mainController', function($scope) {
    // create a message to display in our view
    $scope.message = 'home page';
    $scope.bodyStyles ={
        "background": "url(../images/someimage.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed", 
        "-webkit-background-size": "cover",
        "-moz-background-size": "cover",
        "-o-background-size": "cover",
        "background-size": "cover"
    }
});

angVenture.controller('aboutController', function($scope) {
    $scope.message = 'another page.';
});

....more controllers for different pages...
```

Would I be better off going about doing this with ui-router?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The beter strategy would be to not do this in `JavaScript` but move all the styles to your css. You can acheive that by adding class using `$scope` variable and define those classes in css:

**Controller**

```
angVenture.controller('mainController', function($scope) {
  // create a message to display in our view
  $scope.message = 'home page';
  $scope.bodyClass = 'main-view';
});
```

**View**

```
<body ng-controller="mainController" ng-class="bodyClass">
```

**CSS**

```
.main-view {
  "background": "url(../images/someimage.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed", 
  "-webkit-background-size": "cover",
  "-moz-background-size": "cover",
  "-o-background-size": "cover",
  "background-size": "cover"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
angVenture.controller('mainController', function($scope, $location) {
      // create a message to display in our view
        var classObject = {"/home":"../images/someimage1.jpg", "/about": "../images/someimage1.jpg" };
        $scope.message = 'home page';
        $scope.imageName = classObject[$location.path()];
    });
```

CSS

```
.main-view {

  "-webkit-background-size": "cover",
  "-moz-background-size": "cover",
  "-o-background-size": "cover",
  "background-size": "cover"
}
```

HTML

```
<body ng-controller="mainController" class="main-view" styel=""background": "url({{imageName}}) no-repeat center center fixed"">
```